# How to trim leading path for sphinx automodule members

Tags: python-sphinx

Is there a directive or approach to trim a portion of the import path from the functions when using automodule?

For example when using the automodule directive I have something like this:

```
.. automodule:: super.cool.thing.my_module
    :members:
    :undoc-members:
```

This nicely produces documentation with the functions in the module but the full path is displayed.  If I set the add_module_names to False, it completely removes all path information and only leaves the function name.  This can be a little confusing if you have similar named functions in multiple modules.  Therefore I'd like the functions to have just a portion of the import path displayed.  So instead of this:

```
super.cool.thing.my_module.my_function(a, b, c)
```

I just want:

```
my_module.my_function(a, b, c)
```

Using the add_module_names directive just shows:

```
my_function(a, b, c)
```

Which isn't desirable in my use case.  Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0):

This is accomplished by using the sys.path.insert() in the config.py file.

From the example above you register the path:

```
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('/some/path/super/cool/thing'))
```

In the Sphinx directive you prune the path already described above:

```
.. automodule:: my_module
    :members:
    :undoc-members:
```

This will now produce documentation with the desired shortened function name of:

```
my_module.my_function(a, b, c)
```